# I have a console problem with the libraries in unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, console

OK, I've been a few hours trying to find a better title, more descriptive but since I wasn't able to, here we go. I have this error displayed on the console:

`Library\PackageCache\com.unity.textmeshpro@2.0.1\Scripts\Runtime\TMP_CoroutineTween.cs(1,3): error CS1056: Unexpected character '`

Indeed it is more than 999 errors but I don't know what they mean and less I know how to solve them.

I tried then with uninstalling and installing again Unity and the Unity Hub and still have this problem. I'm a starter indie developer and having Unity in my PC the next days or weeks is REALLY IMPORTANT, please, if someone knows what causes this or even better how to solve it, tell me

Comment: what is the unity version? try going to the package manager and updating textmeshpro

Comment: Try to go to your project folder and delete the entire Library folder. Then open your project in Unity again.

Comment: Matter is that it appears when I have an empty project. I have the latest version 2019 4-0. I'll try by updating the textmeshpro